# Updated CKeditor, now the copy / cut context menu options are gone. How do I get them back?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

They don't even exist on the official demo: http://ckeditor.com/demo

Normally, if nothing was selected, copy / pasted would just be disabled. But only paste shows up in the menu.

How do I get copy / cut back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

highlight text to cut/copy in ckeditor and right click

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli you need to right-click above the selected text.